# Bound Parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I’ve previously asked a question related to this topic as well and with the aid of that question I’ve found the name of exactly what I wanted: “**bound parameters**”.

I have managed to create a routing like "user/:id/dosomething" by adding a member to the `routes.rb`. However, this type of URL is not the solution I was looking for.

My question is, how do you provide the 'user/dosomething/:id' to match with action user's `dosomething` action with `id` sent as parameter?

Here is [the section I’ve read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) in order to get the idea:

> #### 3.1 Bound Parameters
>
> When you set up a regular route, you supply a series of symbols that
>   Rails maps to parts of an incoming HTTP request. Two of these symbols
>   are special: `:controller` maps to the name of a controller in your
>   application, and `:action` maps to the name of an action within that
>   controller. For example, consider this route:
>
> ```
> get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
> ```
>
> If an incoming request of `/photos/show/1` is processed by this route
>   (because it hasn’t matched any previous route in the file), then the
>   result will be to invoke the show action of the `PhotosController`, and
>   to make the final parameter `"1"` available as `params[:id]`. This route
>   will also route the incoming request of `/photos` to
>   `PhotosController#index`, since `:action` and `:id` are optional
>   parameters, denoted by parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom route:

```
get 'user/doesomething/:id' => 'users#do_something', :as => 'do_something_user'
```

This will route HTTP `GET` requests that match the URL `user/dosomething/:id` to the `UsersController`'s `do_something` action.  The `:as => 'do_something_user'` part names the route, so that you can use `do_something_user_path` and `do_something_user_url` helpers to generate the URLs.

For more information on routing, see [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).